# How was the expected value of this derived

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I need help with understanding how the expected value was derived for this question:

[image]

I know how to calculate the expected value for when $\theta=0$ and $\theta=1$, but in the solutions, the expected value is $(17-8\theta)p$, but I'm not sure how they got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s just a convenient way of writing down the answer. It should match your own answer if you did it correctly. To see this, suppose that $\theta=1$. Compare your answer to that given in the solution. Do the same for $\theta=0$.

Comment: If $\theta=0$ then $E[X]=p+4p+12p=17p$ and if $\theta=1$ then $E[X]=p+2p+6p=9p$. I don't see how this can get me to the expected value in the solutions

Comment: @AlexTwin If $\theta=0$, then $(17-8\theta)p=17p$.

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb right now lol